# Rails4 and Elasticsearch as db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I would like to use Elasticsearch to store my Rails models and therefore not only as a way to obtain fast search and apply complex queries (as most of the online tutorials and [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-LrUN6jal8#t=21) do). After some googling I decided to use [flex](https://github.com/ddnexus/flex).

Using flex I am able to save my models to elasticsearch but I have some issues after the creation of the model/resource, in fact if I redirect the user to the list of all the resources I don't see the one that was created before the redirection. Only after a while (e.g. 1 second) I can refresh the page and see it in the list.

So my question here is: is it recommended/possible to use Elasticsearch to persist the models? Or should I use it only to get fast search?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic search provide a persistence functionnality ([Link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-store.html)), I know that it can be implemented using [Tire](https://github.com/karmi/retire), the gem is still maintained (look at the commits)